# Multi-level grouping in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of records with the following structure: (Simplified example!)

```
class Rate
{
    string Code;
    double InterestFrom;
    double InterestTo;
    double IncomeFrom;
    double IncomeTo;
    double Value;
}
```

And yes, I have a List<Rate> defined. I need to convert this list to the following *simplified* structure:

```
class RateList
{
   List<Code> code;
}
class Code
{
    string code;
    List<Interest> interest;
}
class Interest
{
    double InterestFrom;
    double InterestTo;
    List<Income> income;
}
class Income
{
    double IncomeFrom;
    double IncomeTo;
    double Value;
}
```

And I would like to do this with a single LINQ query. I can work out other solutions but the challenge is to do it within one LINQ statement.
Basically, the top-level group is grouped by code. The next level by the values InterestFrom and InterestTo and the lowest level is a list of IncomeFrom, IncomeTo and Value.

So, what would be the LINQ statement for this?

Comment: Can you supply a list of input Rates and the desired output?

Comment: The desired output is a single object of type RateList. InterestFrom/InterestTo and IncomeFrom/IncomeTo are repeating values for every code. An example record would be: ("AB", 0, 6, 10000, 20000, 40.3) or ("AB", 6, 7.5, 10000, 20000, 40.3).

Comment: You mention "the lowest level is grouped by IncomeFrom and IncomeTo." - If this is the case, will the `Value`s be summed? Or did you not actually mean to group on those values? (stopping at interest)

Comment: @Ryan Versaw, You're correct. The lowest level would be on interest, not income.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is pretty huge, but here is what I have:

```
var rateList = new RateList
               {
                   code = (from r in rates
                           group r by r.Code into g
                           select new Code
                           {
                               code = g.Key,
                               interest = (from i in g
                                           group i by new {i.InterestFrom, i.InterestTo} into g2
                                           select new Interest
                                           {
                                               InterestFrom = g2.Key.InterestFrom,
                                               InterestTo = g2.Key.InterestTo,
                                               income = (from inc in g2
                                                         select new Income
                                                         {
                                                             IncomeFrom = inc.IncomeFrom,
                                                             IncomeTo = inc.IncomeTo,
                                                             Value = inc.Value
                                                         }).ToList()
                                           }).ToList()
                           }).ToList()
               };
```

Comment: Huge is no problem. :-) Just want to know if it can be done in a single statement. (And then checking if it stays readable...)

Comment: This is the most concise way I can think to do it right now. The only good way I know of for you to shorten it would be to have some simple constructors on those classes. It wouldn't cut too much out, but it would help a little.

Comment: And checked the code! It works! It's a monster statement but then again, I want to discourage the less experienced developers from modifying it. And to be honest, it's still very readable.

Comment: Shortening isn't really needed. Modifying the constructors isn't possible, though, since the classes I use are not created by me. Still, the final code is less than 30 lines and still readable, as long as you use a wide screen. :-) (Basically, I'm filling this structure to pass it onwards to a third-party module, which probably translates it back to a flat table again.)